# Kotlin Generic Interfaces and type variance problem

Tags: kotlin, generics, type-conversion, variance, type-projection

I come from Java so I'm relatively new with Kotlin. Yesterday afternoon I was trying to understand why cannot achieve this behaviour with type generics in Kotlin:

I have the following declarations:

```
data class Parent(val a : Double)
data class Child(val a : Double, val b : String) : Parent(a)
... more Parent derived classes


interface Foo<T : Parent> {
   fun setValue(v : T)
}


class ChildFooImpl : Foo<Child> {
   override fun setValue(v : Child) {
      ...
   }
}
... more Foo implementations with Parent derived types
```

Next, I need to have a map to store some Foo implementations indexed by class type:

```
val myStore : Map<KClass<out Parent>, Foo<out Parent>> =  mapOf(
   Child::class to ChildFooImpl(),
   ... more Pair creation
)
```

And here comes the problem: Why do I obtain a *Type mismatch: inferred type is Child but Nothing was expected* error when calling *setValue()* method of the retrieved item from map?

```
val theImpl = myStore[Child::class]
theImpl?.setValue(Child(0.0, "aaa"))  // <------- The error
```

`theImpl` has `Foo<out Parent>?` type so I don't figure out why is this happening. I read the Kotlin documentation page about Generics and Type Safety but cannot understand the issue whith the type projection.

Some clear explanation would be really appreciated.

Comment: You wouldn't be able to do this in Java either. Try writing the same code in Java. You need an unchecked cast here in any case.

Comment: You're right, I was confused. I've just verified in Java and it not allowed to do so. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Nothing in the type of the `myStore` map guarantees any relationship between the type of the key in the map, and the type of the corresponding `Foo` value.

So, when you do `val theImpl = myStore[Child::class]`, the only thing you know about `theImpl` is that it's a `Foo<out Parent>`. It could be a `Foo<OtherChild>` for instance, which only accepts `OtherChild` values, not any arbitrary value of other subtypes of `Parent`. So `theImpl.setValue(...)` is not safe to call with anything at all (thus `Nothing` is expected).

The usual way to deal with this would be to wrap this map into a custom type that ensures you control the values that are put in there. The custom function to insert elements would enforce that the key matches the generic type of the `Foo` value, and the custom getter function would perform an unchecked cast (that you know is safe) on the value it returns.